# Is synthetic here referring to a semi synthetic oil?

Tags: oil

I need a 10w40 semi synthetic oil preferably shell helix brand.

Having looked at their site the bottles seemed to be labelled ‘synthetic’ and not ‘semi synthetic’.  However from the site it seems synthetic maybe referring to semi synthetic all of these seem to be listed under semi synthetic though the bottles go on to say synthetic, would I be right?

https://www.shell.com/motorist/oils-lubricants/helix-for-cars/helix-semi-synthetic.html

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. The link you posted shows the Shell Helix HX7 oil, which is a semi-synthetic oil. Shell Helix series oil appears to have a naming schema with an increasing number, where HX3 and HX5 are non-synthetic, HX7 is semi-synthetic (a blend of conventional and synthetic oils), and HX8 and Ultra are fully-synthetic oils. See the bottom of this page for more in the oil lineup. https://www.shell.com/motorist/oils-lubricants/helix-for-cars.html

Comment: Usually fully synthetic oils are lighter weight than their conventional counterparts. I don't know why. When I look at the Shell Helix fully synthetic oils, I don't see 10w40, only 10w30 and lighter.

What does your car manual recommend? Most newer vehicles require 10w30 or lighter.
Putting a non-synthetic oil or a semi-synthetic oil in your car is fine. Synthetic oils last longer before breaking down, and can sometimes provide better protection (in theory at least), but it's far more important that you have the correct oil weight for your car than that it be synthetic.

Comment: @the_storyteller well if hx7 means semi synthetic then I was right.  I was confused as the hx7 bottle states synthetic rather than semi synthetic.

Comment: I'd guess that they put "synthetic technologies" on the semi synthetic bottles because synthetic sells well. It's probably semi-synthetic. They seem to say "fully synthetic" on their fully synthetic oils.

Comment: "Putting a non-synthetic oil or a semi-synthetic oil in your car is fine." It might be fine if you have an old design engine and follow the USA mantra of changing your oil as often as you change your shirt. If you have a reasonably modern engine with an oil change interval of say 18,000miles /  30,000km, stick to what the manufacturers recommended!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you posted shows the Shell Helix HX7 oil, which the Shell site claims is a semi-synthetic oil.

Shell Helix series oil appears to have the following naming schema

```
Name    Bottle Label          Type
--------------------------------------------
HX2     High Mileage          Conventional
HX3     High Mileage          Conventional
HX5     High Mileage          Conventional     
HX6     Synthetic Technology  Semi-Synthetic
HX7     Synthetic Technology  Semi-Synthetic
HX8     Fully Synthetic       Synthetic
Ultra   Fully Synthetic       Synthetic
```

I'm guessing that they say "Synthetic Technology" instead of "Semi-Synthetic" because it sells better.

See the bottom of [the product page](https://shell.com/motorist/oils-lubricants/helix-for-cars.html) for more in the Shell Helix lineup.